# knockoutjs with mvc collection model binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, model-binding

I'm using knockoutjs to render a collection of items.  After allowing the user to do some inline editing I need to post the collection back to the server.  However, the collection isn't being populated on the server because I'm not using the name="[0].Blah" naming convention.  Does anyone know how to either render name attributes like this using knockoutjs OR how to create a model binder that will allow me to extract the values from the ValueProvider?

You can see a screenshot of the ValueProvider during debugging below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOyE9.png

Here is my managed ViewModel:

```
public class FundLevelInvestmentUploadResult
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public IList<FundLevelInvestmentViewModel> Items { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfErrors { get; set; }

    public bool ShowErrorsOnly { get; set; }

    public FundLevelInvestmentUploadResult()
    {
        Items = new List<FundLevelInvestmentViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Here is the managed class for "Items":

```
public class FundLevelInvestmentViewModel
{
    private string _fund;
    private string _fundType;
    private string _date;
    private string _netOfWaivedFees;
    private string _waivedFees;
    private string _bcip;
    private string _fxRate;

    public uint RowIndex { get; set; }

    public int? DealCode { get; set; }
    public bool DealCodeIsValid { get; set; }

    public string Fund
    {
        get { return _fund; }
        set { _fund = GetString(value); }
    }
    public bool FundIsValid { get; set; }

    public string FundType
    {
        get { return _fundType; }
        set { _fundType = GetString(value); }
    }
    public bool FundTypeIsValid { get; set; }

    public string DateOfInvestment
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set { _date = GetString(value); }
    }
    public bool DateOfInvestmentIsValid { get; set; }

    public string NetOfWaivedFees
    {
        get { return _netOfWaivedFees; }
        set { _netOfWaivedFees = GetString(value); }
    }
    public bool NetOfWaivedFeesIsValid { get; set; }

    public string WaivedFee
    {
        get { return _waivedFees; }
        set { _waivedFees = GetString(value); }
    }
    public bool WaivedFeeIsValid { get; set; }

    public string BCIP
    {
        get { return _bcip; }
        set { _bcip = GetString(value); }
    }
    public bool BCIPIsValid { get; set; }

    public string ExchangeRateToUSD
    {
        get { return _fxRate; }
        set { _fxRate = GetString(value); }
    }
    public bool ExchangeRateToUSDIsValid { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }

    private IList<string> _errors;
    public IList<string> Errors
    {
        get { return _errors ?? (_errors = new List<string>());}
        set { _errors = value; }
    }

    public bool Show { get; set; }

    public FundLevelInvestmentViewModel()
    {
        Errors = new List<string>();
        Show = true;
    }

    // knockoutjs is returning "null" instead of "" for a null object when calling ko.mapping.fromJS
    private string GetString(string value)
    {
        if (value == "null")
            return string.Empty;

        return value;
    }
}
```

Here is my knockout viewModel:

```
var viewModel = {
    FileData: ko.observableArray([]),

    validateFile: function (file, event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: newUrl,
            data: ko.mapping.toJS(file)
        }).done(function (data) {
            var newFile = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
            var index = file.Items.indexOf(file);
            viewModel.FileData.replace(file, newFile);
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: If you are sending back to the server with `toJSON` it should work. Can you post your Model?

Comment: have you tried posting `file.FileData`?

Comment: I don't want to post all of FileData.  Just an individual element of FileData which is a complete FundLevelInvestmentUploadResult instance.

Comment: Ah, I was confused as to the collection being posted. So, does the object get populated with an empty `Items` collection, or is the whole thing empty?

Comment: Oddly enough, there are the correct number of Items in the collection but all of the properties of each item are the default values (null for string, 0 for int, etc).

Comment: I know you want that method check later, but to test, does it work with auto properties? Because the default binder should handle JSON => List just fine.

Comment: how are you getting your data into your model to begin with?

Comment: I'm getting the data into the model when a user uploads a file.  In the  post response handler I'm adding to viewModel.FileData.  It may be worth noting that I can send an individual item to the server without a problem.  It is only a problem when I send a collection.

Comment: I'm hoping that I don't have to go the brute force way and add another property for each property of each Item specifically for the Name property.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific.  Are you using the knockout.mapping plugin to get the data into the viewmodel or did you hand code it?  I've had really good results with using the mapping plugin to make sure arrays and such are properly binded on the server side.

Comment: I'm using knockout.mapping to get the data into the viewModel and to get it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using version 2.1.0.0 or later of knockout you can render the name attribute as follows from an observable array.

```
<input data-bind='attr: { name: "Items["+$index()+"].DealCode"}' />
```

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't working.  I don't understand why. <input type="text" data-bind='value: $data.DealCode, disable: $data.DealCodeIsValid, attr: { name: "Items["+$index()+"].DealCode", id: "Items_"+$index()+"__DealCode"}' class="input-mini" />

It seems to be providing the correct HTML:
<input type="text" class="input-mini" disabled="" name="Items[0].DealCode" id="Items_0__DealCode">