# Post a Javascript array not working with DefaultModelBinder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, knockout.js, model-binding

### Code

I can not send an array of javascript objects to the server.
ModelBinder standard does not recognize the format.

**On my server I have classes:**

```
public class PessoaViewModel
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
    public string CPF { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TelefoneViewModel> Telefones { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EnderecoViewModel> Enderecos { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EmailViewModel> Emails { get; set; }
    public PessoaViewModel Conjuge { get; set; }
}

public class TelefoneViewModel
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [AdditionalMetadata("class", "span2")]
    [AdditionalMetadata("placeholder", "Tipo")]
    public string Tipo { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [AdditionalMetadata("class", "span2")]
    public string Numero { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int Ordem { get; set; }
}
```

> I'm not listing the rest of the class because it is not yet used in the code!

**My javascript**

```
$.ajax
    url:  $(form).attr("action")
    type: "POST"
    error: (err, errType, errMessage) -> 
        console.error a.statusText
    cache: false
    data: ko.mapping.toJS(@, ignoreFunctionsMapping) 
    success: (data, txtStatus) -> console.log "OK!!?? On server maybe not!"
```

**Server result**

[image: Action binder]

> Full image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeIm1.jpg

### Question

As you can see, the post is being done and the values ​​are correct.
But asp.net mvc does not fill correctly the `Telefones` object!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11182113/1373170
The default model binder uses the following naming convention for collections: Telefonos[0].Numero, which is slightly different than the one you are using.

Comment: The problem is that this convention was generated by jquery or by the browser (I can not say for sure) when I make the post.   


Remember that I am sending the data as javascript object and not the conventional way would be `$("form").serialize()`

Comment: Did you try using submit() just to check how it behaves ? I am having the same problem =/

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because you are missing a ".", it should have the format:

```
Telefones[0].Id: 1
Telefones[0].Ordem: bli
```